# MySQL SELECT IN with sub-query

Tags: mysql

Alright, so I am having issue with the following.. I am trying to do a single select statement with two sub queries. What I need it to do is the following pretty much..

`SELECT * FROM messages WHERE` the following conditions are meet.

condition  1:

```
 SELECT id 
 FROM messages 
 WHERE `receiver` = 123510 && sender= 123457 && status != 3;
```

condition  2:

```
 SELECT id 
 FROM messages 
 WHERE receiver = 123457 && sender = 123510 && status !=4;
```

I tried doing the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE id IN (
                 (
                     SELECT id 
                     FROM messages 
                     WHERE `receiver` = 123510 && sender= 123457 && status != 3
                 ),
                 (
                     SELECT id 
                     FROM messages 
                     WHERE receiver = 123457 && sender = 123510 && status !=4)
                  )
```

but when I do that mysql comes back with Subquery returns more than 1 row...

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just `or` the two clauses together? `where (r=1 and s=2 and status != 3) or (r=2 and s=1 and status != 4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE (receiver = 123510 AND sender = 123457 AND status <> 3) OR
      (receiver = 123457 AND sender = 123510 AND status <> 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to separate each query with a union or do it as two separate INs separated with an OR.

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE id IN (
          SELECT id
          FROM messages
          WHERE `receiver` = 123510 and 
                sender= 123457 and 
                status != 3) or
          UNION
          SELECT id
          FROM messages 
          WHERE receiver = 123457 and 
          sender = 123510 and
          status !=4)
```

But really, it would be much better to do this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE (`receiver` = 123510 and 
       sender = 123457 and 
       status != 3) or
      (receiver = 123457 and 
       sender = 123510 and
       status !=4)
```